# Trouble with THREE.CubeTextureLoader

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create 3d dice with texture maps on a cube. If I just load a single texture it displays fine (although, of course, I can't specify different images for each side). I tried using CubeTextureLoader but I get a totally garbled texture ([Here's what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kobNR.png)). Any suggestions?

```
// This doesn't work
THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load(['/public/images/dice6-red.png',
                        '/public/images/dice6-red.png',
                        '/public/images/dice6-red.png',
                        '/public/images/dice6-red.png',
                        '/public/images/dice6-red.png',
                        '/public/images/dice6-red.png'], function(texture) {

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2,2,2 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff,
                                                map: texture});
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    cube.position.x = 10;
    cube.position.y = -20;
    self._scene.add(cube);
    self.update();
});

// This works fine
new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/public/images/dice6-red.png', function(texture) {

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2,2,2 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff,
                                                map: texture});
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    cube.position.y = -20;
    self._scene.add(cube);
    self.update();
});
```

Comment: CubeTextureLoader is for loading skymaps, not really for adding textures on a "cube"  mesh. Not to say that it can't be adapted, just that that is not what it was meant for.

Answer (score 1):

To place different images on the sides of a cube in the current version of Three.js (v93), use an array of materials in the mesh constructor. For example:

```
let cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
let materialArray = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("xpos.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("xneg.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("ypos.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("yneg.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("zpos.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("zneg.png") } ),
];
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, materialArray );
```