# Three.js - Using CubeTextureLoader to create a different image on each face of a cube

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to create a cube with a different image on each side using `CubeTextureLoader`. My process is:

1. Load a cube texture using `new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()`
2. Create a new material using the cube texture
3. Create a cube using this material
4. Draw the cube

The relevant code is below. I can draw a cube with a single material for all faces fine using `THREE.TextureLoader()`, but when I use `CubeTextureLoader` I get nothing onscreen or any console errors.

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();

textureLoader.load([
    'textures/face-1.jpg',
    'textures/face-2.jpg',
    'textures/face-3.jpg',
    'textures/face-4.jpg',
    'textures/face-5.jpg',
    'textures/face-6.jpg'
 ], function (texture) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        map: texture
    });

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20),
        material
    );

    // add & draw calls happen after all this
});
```

I'm guessing I'm using the wrong Material type or Mesh but can't find any info or examples on how to do this correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: check comment on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333088/trouble-with-three-cubetextureloader) question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Micnil mentioned, `CubeTextureLoader` is for CubeMap which is used for SkyBox or EnvMap.

Use `MeshFaceMaterial` instead.

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var texture0 = textureLoader.load( './0.jpg' );
var texture1 = textureLoader.load( './1.jpg' );
var texture2 = textureLoader.load( './2.jpg' );
var texture3 = textureLoader.load( './3.jpg' );
var texture4 = textureLoader.load( './4.jpg' );
var texture5 = textureLoader.load( './5.jpg' );

var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture0 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture1 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture2 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture3 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture4 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture5 } )
];
var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 20, 20 );
var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, faceMaterial );
```

Comment: `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial` has been replaced by `THREE.MultiMaterial` (since r72 i believe)

Comment: @yomotsu How make this in v0.91.0? MeshFaceMaterial removed since v0.72.. :(

Comment: @AdsonCicilioti In the current version (v93), you use an array of materials, see my posted answer to this question.

Answer (score 9):

`THREE.MultiMaterial` has also been removed, as described in: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10931

Now, you can use an array of materials in the mesh constructor instead. For example:

```
let cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
let materialArray = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("xpos.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("xneg.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("ypos.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("yneg.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("zpos.png") } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: loader.load("zneg.png") } ),
];
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, materialArray );
```