# Trying to view the scene with a perspective camera into a cube

Tags: three.js

In threejs, I'm trying to create a cubemap with the camera inside the cube. But the texture is white or black (with the change of the mapping property to `UVMapping` or `CubeReflectionMapping`). Is it because I'm inside the cube and it's not working ?

I wish to view the texture into the cube. I'm using a `CubeTextureLoader()` and `load( urls )` (a list of 6 urls).

And I'm creating a cube and I set the `envMap` in `cube.material.envMap` with the cubemap texture. But, the texture is white into the cube. The material property `side` is set to `THREE.DoubleSide`.

Note that the camera (a perspective camera) is placed into the cube.

How can I resolve it ?

If I'm creating a specific geometry (a lounge, for example) instead of a BoxGeometry, the texture is visible (with `envMap` setting) into the object rendered.

Also, it works using a sphere geometry.

The code example:

```
let cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000, 1000, 1000 )
    let cubeMap = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
    let cubeTexture = await cubeMap.load( [ urls[0], urls[1], urls[2], urls[3], urls[4], urls[5] ] )
    cubeTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    cubeTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    let cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { envMap : cubeTexture, side : THREE.DoubleSide } )
    let cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeo, cubeMaterial )
    this.scene.add(cubeMesh)
```

Maybe, this link explains the solution to use a BoxGeometry and MeshFaceMaterial.

[Three.js - Using CubeTextureLoader to create a different image on each face of a cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877484/three-js-using-cubetextureloader-to-create-a-different-image-on-each-face-of-a?rq=2)